# Include .css and .js file in Node.js project

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I used Node.js and Angular.js to build a simple web application based on Express framework, when I try to upload a `.css` file, I got the following error message :

`“The stylesheet was not loaded because its MIME type, ”text/html“ is not ”text/css"`

**server.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var pg = require('pg');
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken'); // create, sign and verify tokens
var morgan = require('morgan');
// Application front end
app.get('*',function(req,res){
  res.sendfile('./public/index.html')
})
app.listen(port);
console.log('LogAnalysisWebApp happens on port '+port);
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Log Analysis Web APP</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/public/stylesheets/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Text Example</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

My project has the following structure :

[image: Project structure]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To serve static files such as images, CSS files, and JavaScript files, use the express.static built-in middleware function in Express.

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

Now, you can load the files that are in the public directory:

```
http://www.domain.com/stylesheets/style.css
```

Here is the [official documentation page](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) on serving static resources.